# Swift: Calling a function within a Core Graphics draw function

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift3, core-graphics

I'm trying to access a certain function which draws some lines using a `UIBezierPath()`. However, the usual process for accessing a nested function is not working, stating that the function is not a member.

To be specific, let's say `class` contains `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` which contains the desired `func()`. My goal is to execute `func()` from another class.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Example Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class figure: UIView {


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 560, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

    circle.center = CGPoint(x: 560, y: 60)
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    circle.clipsToBounds = true

    let circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25.0, y: 25.0, width: 90.0, height: 90.0))

    circle2.center = circle.center
    circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 45
    circle2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    circle2.clipsToBounds = true

    /*
    var darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    var blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)

    blurView.frame = circle.bounds

    circle.addSubview(blurView)
    */
    addSubview(circle)
    addSubview(circle2)

    let spine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 560, y: 110, width: 10, height: 110))
    func spineDraw(){
        spine.center = CGPoint(x: 560, y: 165)
        spine.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        spine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        spine.clipsToBounds = true
        addSubview(spine)
    }
    var shoulder = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 120)
    var rElbow = CGPoint(x: 410 + rElbowXGlobal.rElbowX, y: 170 + rElbowYGlobal.rElbowY)
    var rWrist = CGPoint(x: 410 + rWristXGlobal.rWristX, y: 195 + rWristYGlobal.rWristY)
    let rArm = UIBezierPath()
    rArm.lineWidth = 5
    func rArmDraw() {
        rArm.move(to: shoulder)
        rArm.addLine(to: rElbow)
        rArm.stroke()
        rArm.addLine(to: rWrist)
        rArm.stroke()
        rArm.close()
    }

    var lElbow = CGPoint(x: 390 + lElbowXGlobal.lElbowX, y: 170 + lElbowYGlobal.lElbowY)
    var lWrist = CGPoint(x: 390 + lWristXGlobal.lWristX, y: 195 + lWristYGlobal.lWristY)
    let lArm = UIBezierPath()
    lArm.lineWidth = 5
    func lArmDraw(){
        lArm.move(to: shoulder)
        lArm.addLine(to: lElbow)
        lArm.stroke()
        lArm.addLine(to: lWrist)
        lArm.stroke()
        lArm.close()
    }

    var hip = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 215)

    var rKnee = CGPoint(x: 410 + rKneeXGlobal.rKneeX, y: 250 + rKneeYGlobal.rKneeY)
    var rAnkle = CGPoint(x: 410 + rAnkleXGlobal.rAnkleX, y: 270 + rAnkleYGlobal.rAnkleY)
    let rLeg = UIBezierPath()
    rLeg.lineWidth = 5
    func rLegDraw(){
        rLeg.move(to: hip)
        rLeg.addLine(to: rKnee)
        rLeg.stroke()
        rLeg.addLine(to: rAnkle)
        rLeg.stroke()
        rLeg.close()
    }

    var lKnee = CGPoint(x: 390 + lKneeXGlobal.lKneeX, y: 250 + lKneeYGlobal.lKneeY)
    var lAnkle = CGPoint(x: 390 + lAnkleXGlobal.lAnkleX, y: 270 + lAnkleYGlobal.lAnkleY)
    let lLeg = UIBezierPath()
    lLeg.lineWidth = 5
    func lLegDraw(){
        lLeg.move(to: hip)
        lLeg.addLine(to: lKnee)
        lLeg.stroke()
        lLeg.addLine(to: lAnkle)
        lLeg.stroke()
        lLeg.close()
    }


    //debug grid
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    for i in 1...10 {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: i*100, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: i*100, y: 1000))
        path.stroke()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: i*100))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2000, y: i*100))
    }
    spineDraw()
    rArmDraw()
    lArmDraw()
    rLegDraw()
    lLegDraw()
   }

}
```

I am trying to execute the five functions at the bottom. I cannot execute anything within this class from another viewController class.

Comment: A better example would be of help. Something showing the actual code you've tried, along with the specific error you are getting. Something duplicatable?

Comment: Your sample code compiles for me (once I define all the globals you're accessing).

Comment: Do you know how I could call one of the five functions listed at the bottom outside of `drawRect(_:)`?